# How can i call own method in django class based api views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to create account using phone number as a username and generate otp code . now i want to validate my phone number. I create a method is_phone_valid to validate my phone number but call it by post method but i am getting an error [image: error image]
This is my views.py

```
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer

    def is_phone_valid(phone_number):
        if phone_number:
            MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$')
            if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.is_phone_valid(phone_number)
```

models.py

```
class TempRegistration(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    otp_code = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number
```

Comment: `phone_number` is in the POST parameters?

Comment: no, you can see post method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/). If so, use [***field-level***--DRF doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#field-level-validation) validation of [DRF Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers), as below

```
# views.py
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer


# serializers.py
class AccountsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate_phone_number(self, phone_number):
        MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$')
        if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
            return phone_number
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('No. not matching')

    class Meta:
        model = TempRegistration
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Note:** You don't need to override the **`post(...)`** method of **`CreateAPIView`** class.

Comment: it can not validate phone number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the phone number in the [POST parameters [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Use_for_submitting_web_forms), then you should access this in `self.request.POST`.

Furthermore you can not return a boolean as the result of a request. This needs to be a `HttpResponse`, for example a [**`JsonResponse`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects):

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer

    def is_phone_valid(self, phone_number):
        if phone_number:
            MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$')
            if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return JsonResponse(
            {'result': self.is_phone_valid(self.request.POST.get('phone_number'))}
        )
```

Comment: i am getting TypeError
is_phone_valid() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: @SajibHossain: yes, you should have added a `self`, or made it a `@staticmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the `phone_number` variable. I hope you're using DRF, then the parameter `phone_number` will be available in `request.data`

```
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer

    def is_phone_valid(phone_number):
        if phone_number:
            MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$')
            if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = request.data['phone_number']
        return Response({'result' : self.is_phone_valid(phone_number)})
```

Answer (score 0):

The traceback you have posted explains that it can't find the `phone_number` you are passing to `self.is_phone_valid(phone_number)` in your post method.

Secondly, your question is how to call the `is_phone_valid` from inside the class? You need to make pass `self` as the first arg of this method.

```
class GetPhoneNumber(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = TempRegistration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountsSerializer

    def is_phone_valid(self, phone_number):
        if phone_number:
            MOBILE_REGEX = re.compile('^(?:\+?88)?01[15-9]\d{8}$')
            if MOBILE_REGEX.match(phone_number):
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        phone_number = request.data['phone_number']
        return self.is_phone_valid(phone_number)
```